# WXWidgets wxListCtrl Example

Tags: c++, user-interface, events, wxwidgets

I have searched all over the internet for a good implementation of wxListCtrl... the reason I am having issues is because I cannot figure out how to implement capturing mouse clicks on anything in the list, everything else is fine. If someone could please share a basic full implementation example of how to capture clicks in wxListCtrl, I would very much appreciate it. I am not sharing any code, because I don't even know where to start. This is a totally new area for me, but I learn quickly.

Comment: what is the purpose of catching the low-level event, such as mouse click? For the code example - you can check the listctrl sample, which is found at the samples directory of the wxWidgets distribution. So please describe what you are looking for to do, so we can help.

Comment: I would simply like to capture a left click event on an item in the list, so I can display the information related to the class with the name of that item. What I want to do, is create a list with 2 columns, which I know how to do. This list will have 2 columns, transaction name and amount. One will be a string, one will be a double. When I click said item in the list, I would like to find that transaction in my list, and display the relevant transaction information. I am designing a C++ budget program to help learn it better. All is well, except for this one part.

Comment: in the sample I mentioned look at the EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED - how it is being processed.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now.